# What does this UWSGI output mean? > "(X switches on core 0)"

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I'm running a `nginx` with `uwsgi` application with `django` that used the `sqlite` structure.

When running `uwsgi`, when a `GET` or `POST` request is made, it sends output such as:

`[pid: 29018|app: 0|req: 39/76] 136.61.69.96 () {52 vars in 1208 bytes} [Wed Jul 19 17:25:12 2017] POST /binaryQuestionApp/?participant=A3AJJHOAV7WIUQ&assignmentId=37QW5D2ZRHPMKY652LHT9QV23ZD8SU => generated 6 bytes in 722 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 3 headers in 195 bytes (1 switches on core 0)`

What does the last bit mean? Sometimes it says 2 switches, sometimes 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presumably you have found the answer, but for anyone that lands here looking for the answer I found this:

> "core" is the low-level concept for uWSGI concurrency context in a
>   process (can be a thread or a greenlet or a fiber or a goroutine and
>   so on...) while switches count is incremented whenever an app "yield"
>   its status (this has various meanings based on the lower concurrency
>   model used)

Source: http://lists.unbit.it/pipermail/uwsgi/2015-March/007949.html